# Python function in function

Tags: python

```
def example(function):
    if input() == "Hello there!":
        #at this point I want to call the function entered in the tuples
```

an example of what I mean:

```
def example(function):
    if input() == "Hello there!":
        #do the function here

def Printer(What_to_print):
    print(What_to_print + "Just an example")


example(Printer)
```

Is this possibe and are there drawbacks in doing this?

Comment: Do you mean passing function as an argument to another function? Yes, it is possible and is quite common.

Comment: Yes it's entirely possible.

Comment: `at this point I want to call the function` - So do that?

Comment: It isn't just possible.  [Several](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) take [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) as [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

Comment: Those things the function's `function` argument is between are called [parentheses](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/parentheses). A [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) is a built-in Python sequence type whose construction can look very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

```
def example(function):
    if input() == "Hello there!":
        function("Hello there!")  # invoke it!
```

Actually you can pass `def` functions and `lambda` functions as parameters and invoke them by `()` syntax.

Comment: Sorry for asking this (i'm really new to coding) but could you give me an example of what you mean by invoking it?

Comment: @AndreasSandberg By invoking, I mean calling the function. In your words, _doing_ the function.

Comment: I probaly sound really stupid right now, but I don't know what to add after the ; and when I remove it the `example` prints what I want it to print without me doing anything, and when I type in Hello there! I just get lots of errors.

Comment: @AndreasSandberg Sorry, my bad! Python doesn't need semicolons. updated my answer.

Comment: this when ran just calls the function in it without me having to type Hello there! and when I type Hello there! it says TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @AndreasSandberg updated my answer again. You can simply pass all needed parameters to the function being called as it would in regular functions calls.

Answer (score 0):

In python, functions are objects like any other common types, like `int`s and `str`s. Therefore, there is no problem with a function that receives another function as an argument.

```
>>> def pr(): print ('yay')

>>> def func(f): f()

>>> isinstance(pr, object)
True
>>> isinstance(int, object)
True
>>> func(pr)
yay
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def example(function, what_to_print):
    if raw_input() == "Hello there!":
        function(what_to_print)

def printer(what_to_print):
    print(what_to_print + "Just an example")

example(printer, "")
```